# Fecha y hora futura en PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, date, datetime

Estoy creando un sistema de vencimientos, y veo que al insertar un campo con formato datetime en phpmyadmin estoy teniendo inconvenientes.
Inicialmente lo codifiqué de la siguiente manera:

```
date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( $_POST['pfecha'] ) ) //la fecha me graba así 1969-12-31 21:00:00.
```

Después de investigar, pude mejorarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$fecha = new DateTime(strtotime( $_POST['fecha'] ));
echo date_format($fecha,"Y-m-d H:i:s"); //me graba fecha y hora actual.
```

Pero de ninguna forma me deja grabar fecha y hora futura, por ejemplo `2022-12-31 23:59:00`.

Comment: Relacionado: [strtotime devuelve 1969-12-31](/q/217037)

Comment: Además, ¡PHPMyAdmin no es una base de datos, es una herramienta de visualización! Tu base de datos ha de ser MySQL o MariaDB, por poner algunos ejemplos. Aunque en tu caso, tu problema es con PHP.

Comment: Ya lo revise y no resuelve el problema de fechas posteriores. independientemente de que "herramienta de visualizacion" utilice.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! "Pero de ninguna manera me deja grabar fecha y hora futura".. porque?? que es lo que pasa cuando mandas esa fecha? manda la fecha de error?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es sumar intervalos a la fecha para luego obtener la fecha futura (es lo que yo entiendo), podrías hacer esto:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime("2006-12-12");
$date->modify("+7 day");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
?>
```

Puedes chequear más detalles [aquí](https://es.answacode.com/stackoverflow/2605446/php-obtener-fecha-y-hora-futura).